# create style xml in java for view (Button)

Tags: java, android, xml

This is my xml style for view (Button)

```
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_pressed="true" >
            <shape>
                <solid
                    android:color="#e92727" />
                <stroke
                    android:width="1dp"
                    android:color="#d30a0a" />
                <corners
                    android:radius="10dp" />
                <padding
                    android:left="10dp"
                    android:top="10dp"
                    android:right="10dp"
                    android:bottom="10dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape>
                <gradient
                    android:startColor="#e92727"
                    android:endColor="#d30a0a"
                    android:angle="270" />
                <stroke
                    android:width="1dp"
                    android:color="#d30a0a" />
                <corners
                    android:radius="10dp" />
                <padding
                    android:left="10dp"
                    android:top="10dp"
                    android:right="10dp"
                    android:bottom="10dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </selector>
```

I want to create this style in java without using xml file from drawable.
Tried to achieve this from [`createFromXML`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#createFromXml(android.content.res.Resources,%20org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser))  but would not succeed.

code :

```
String xml_code = initalized with above xml code;
Drawable d = null;
XmlPullParserFactory pullParserFactory;
try {
      pullParserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
      XmlPullParser parser = pullParserFactory.newPullParser(); 
      InputStream in_s = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml_code.getBytes("UTF-8"));
      parser.setInput(in_s, null);
      d = Drawable.createFromXml(getResources(), parser);
} catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
btn.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```

Please suggest how i can achieve this and its not possible for me to save this xml in drawable and use it further like `btn.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.xml_style));`

Comment: Try `button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,R.drawable.your_xml, 0, 0);`

Comment: Did you try `btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_xml)`?

Comment: @Aniruddha i dont want to use XML file for styling want to create same with Java code.Please suggest if there is any way to do this.

Comment: May I know why you don't want to use xml?

Comment: In app user will be allowed to customize views.Dynamically modifying xml won't be possible but it can be done through java.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand. Why would you using Java instead of xml ? 
XML is easier x)

And i think you're confusing things.

You can do that :

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.layout.your_xml_file);
```

That will return you a drawable from your xml file.

I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: Yes you are right XML is much easier but i want to create it from Java as its my app requirement.

Comment: Can you develop this. I don't see why :) May be i don't understand

Comment: In app user will be allowed to customize views.Dynamically modifying xml won't be possible but it can be done through java.

Comment: It depend on what you want to modify but for example if you want to choose between EditText and Textview, you can put both in the xml file. One with visibility = gone and the other to visibility = visible. And you change that through java with setVisibility().

Comment: modification will be based on xml code i have posted. Like Stroke,Corner,Padding,state_pressed

Comment: I don't know sorry. May be using abstract class [ShapeDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ShapeDrawable.html)